# Y position of the component to the screen, where the component is above the other components

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to get every activity, especially the focus position. I make code like this, but the results obtained if the component is above the other components get an incorrect value. what is incorrect in the following code?

```
procedure TForm1.FormFocusChanged(Sender: TObject);
var
  LFocused : TControl;
  LFocusRect: TRectF;
  P: TPointF;
begin
  if Assigned(Focused) then
  begin
    LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
    LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;//to get height,top,etc
    P := ClientToScreen(LFocused.Position.Point);

    Text1.Text := 'Y '+ P.Y.ToString;
  end;
end;
```

this is the interface

[image]

Comment: Do you take account of the relative coordinate to the ClientRect of the ScrollBox?

Comment: I did not take this into account, because I assumed the scrollbar was in a fixed condition

Answer (score 1):

just change this line:

```
P := ClientToScreen(LFocused.Position.Point);
```

to

```
P := LFocused.LocalToAbsolute(PointF(0,0));
```